# Send a 'click' to Google Analytics from ruby

Tags: ruby, google-analytics

I'm building an app with some 'mail tracking' feature and want to notify google analytics about a click in a link from ruby.

I've already changed all external links from email to go to my server to be redirected, so I know what and when the user clicked.

I want to send this click just knowing the 'UA-XXXXX' and the clicked url.

Is there a way? Or the best solution is to render a html page and with JS send the click event?

**UPDATE**: Ok, I've found [gabba](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gabba/) but don't know how to send an 'click' event.

Comment: How are you using Ruby? As a scraper or like as a web framework hosting the app (Rails)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally its better to use the JS api, since it has access to all of the other data that analytics tracks, like the visitor browser/os/geoip and can tie all that to a 'visit'.

If you are embedding links in emails, you might consider using the source/medium/campaign flags in the links.

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033867

So technically its not tracking the 'clicks' as an event, more like tracking the fact that the user came to your site from that particular email.  You could use a separate campaign label if you wanted the individual click granularity. (If, for example you had the same url in the email more than once and you wanted to know whether they clicked the first or second one in the email)

Comment: The problem is that I want to track link to external sites(not my site), so in this case will I need to use the html + js solution to send the click event and redirect to the correct url?